# Characters replacement with array key/value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to replace some specials characters (emojis) based on a replacement map.
I wrote this piece of code but it still not work..

```
var char_map = {
    '■': 'e',
    '­♥': 'a',
    '♦': 'm',
};

$.fn.map_replace = function() {
    $(this).html(function(i, content) {
        $.each(char_map, function(key, value) {
            content = content.replace(key, value);
        });
        return content;
    });
};

$(".comment").map_replace();
```

[This code on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NaX6v/)

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: what encoding are you using on the file?

Comment: Pages are UTF-8 Encoded.

Comment: Your code is actually working - it's just that replace only replaces the first instance of the character (note that "Lorem" is correctly changed each time). Unfortunately, getting characters like that working with regex is beyond me at this time in the morning, but that's your problem. You can use any one of a number of "replaceAll" snippets you can find anywhere to give you the functionality you need. Also, there's an error on line 4 - the trailing comma will break in IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use escape codes instead of literal Unicode characters, and replace them using regular expressions:

```
var char_map = {
    'e' : /\u25A0/g,
    'a' : /\u2665/g,
    'm' : /\u2666/g,
};

$.fn.map_replace = function() {
    $(this).html(function(i, content) {
        $.each(char_map, function(character, regex) {
            content = content.replace(regex, character);
        });
        return content;
    });
};

$(".comment").map_replace();
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KK6nk/1/)

The reason your initial approach didn't work is that by default String.replace() only replaces the *first* occurrence of the search expression. By using a regex and specifying the "g" (for "global") flag, you can tell it to replace all matches.